# Malloc, Pointers and Variables

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, pointer-to-member

First of, thank you for taking your time. I am trying to understand what the particular code showed below is trying to do so as to convert them into python. The first line is to allocate memory to pointer (aPointContour) which I am aware python do not have. The second line is to obtain random number within iContourLenght. The third line allocates value (2*aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].x + aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].y) to matrix (pMatA) at row 0 and column 0.

My question:

1) What is "aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].x" trying to do?

2) The purpose of .x .y?

My thought:

1) Accessing memory located at "iRandomPoint1" within pointer, "aPointContour". The value needed to be placed into matrix "pMatA" is "2*iRandomPoint1", and according to the code below accessing memory should not give us "iRandomPoint1" value?

2) Is .x and .y part of Cvpoint or in general used as a member of pointer "aPointContour"? If it's a member will it be for reference purpose only or actual mathematical significance?

My apologies for the long post, really hope someone could help me out. Thanks you any kind sir or madam in advanced! :)

```
// C++
CvPoint *aPointContour = (CvPoint *) malloc(sizeof(CvPoint) * iContourLength);
iRandomPoint1 = (int)((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1) * iContourLength);
cvmSet(pMatA, 0, 0,2* aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].x + aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `aPointContour` is a pointer to an array of `CvPoint` objects. `aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].x` uses `iRandomPoint1` as the index into the array, then accesses the `x` member variable within that object.
2. `.x` and `.y` access member variables of objects. This is analogous to accessing object properties in Python. These are members of the `CvPoint` class. Look for a declaration of `class CvPoint` or `struct CvPoint` somewhere in the code (probably in a header file), it will declare all the member variables and functions.

The only real problem with this code is that it's using uninitialized values of the array elements. `malloc()` allocates memory, but it doesn't fill it in with anything predictable. So unless you've left out code that fills in the array, when it accesses `aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].x` and `aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].y`, undefined behavior occurs.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I do find it weird to not have any values in the array, CvPoint. I will look further into it to see if I have left out anything. Again, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What is "aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].x" trying to do?

Well lets start with iRandomPoint1.  It is a integer between 0 and iContourLength, the size of the array aPointContour.  Therefore aPointContour[iRandomPoint1] is a random CvPoint initialized by the first line.  aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].x is accessing the x value of CvPoint.

In the context of your example, honestly it doesn't make much sense, as it hasn't been initialized whatsover.  The memory has been created, but the values will all be the contents of memory up until the point in which the space was allocated (for all intents and purposes, nonsensical).

> 2) The purpose of .x .y?

".x" means return the value of x denoted by type CvPoint.  Again in the context of this code, it would be unassigned and therefore nonsensical.  Adding aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].x with aPointContour[iRandomPoint1].y is equally nonsensical.  If a pointer were passed in instead, one could argue that it is being passed to the method to be assigned, but that isn't even the case.

It doesn't make much sense without first assigning these values to something.  It's like dumping the contents of a black box into your batter to make a cake with.  Who knows what sort of cake will come out of something like that?

Comment: Hi Neil,thank you so much for the detailed explanation and possible troubleshooting. Appreciate your effort and time! I will be sure to look into it deeper to see if I missed out on any details. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Marrior Happy to help.  :)